# can a for loop be avoided when comparing matrices?

Tags: r

I am looking at the [caseMatch](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=caseMatch)  package which I would like to apply to some of my own data, but it is running prohibitively slowly on my data. I am wondering whether the issue might be with the use of for loops at a point in the process where a lot of comparing is going on.  Here is some sample code to set things up, based on what happens in the caseMatch package:

```
objects = 5 # number of objects
sample_size = 3 # size of sample

# make a matrix of dummy data
set.seed(1)
holder <- matrix(runif(n=objects^2, min=1, max=20), nrow=objects)

# make a matrix of pairings
pairings <- t(combn(sample_size,2))

# make a matrix of combinations
combinations <- t(combn(objects,sample_size))
```

I want a table which makes each of the comparisons listed in the pairings matrix (i.e. 1 vs 2, 1 vs 3, 2 vs 3), applied to each row of the combinations matrix, and returning values from the holder matrix. This is adapted from the code in the caseMatch package which does this:

```
holder2 <- matrix(NA,nrow(combinations),(choose(sample_size,2)))
colnames(holder2)<- paste(pairings[,1],"-",pairings[,2], sep="")
for(k in 1:(choose(sample_size,2))){
    for(i in 1:nrow(combinations)){
        holder2[i,k] <- holder[combinations[i,pairings[k,2]],combinations[i,pairings[k,1]]]
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
            1-2       1-3       2-3
 [1,]  8.070354 11.884214 13.555158
 [2,]  8.070354 18.255948 12.953167
 [3,]  8.070354  4.831957  2.173939
 [4,] 11.884214 18.255948  8.297971
 [5,] 11.884214  4.831957 15.626987
 [6,] 18.255948  4.831957 15.771459
 [7,] 13.555158 12.953167  8.297971
 [8,] 13.555158  2.173939 15.626987
 [9,] 12.953167  2.173939 15.771459
[10,]  8.297971 15.626987 15.771459
```

Is there a more efficient way to return this information (e.g. using apply) which might speed things up?

*EDIT*: structure of matrices

holder matrix:

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,]  6.044665 18.069404  4.913517 10.456286 18.759399
[2,]  8.070354 18.948830  4.354578 14.634752  5.030708
[3,] 11.884214 13.555158 14.053434 19.846216 13.381802
[4,] 18.255948 12.953167  8.297971  8.220668  3.385547
[5,]  4.831957  2.173939 15.626987 15.771459  6.077193
```

pairings matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    2    3
```

combinations matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
 [2,]    1    2    4
 [3,]    1    2    5
 [4,]    1    3    4
 [5,]    1    3    5
 [6,]    1    4    5
 [7,]    2    3    4
 [8,]    2    3    5
 [9,]    2    4    5
[10,]    3    4    5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vectorize by using matrix indexing:

```
matrix(
  holder[matrix(combinations[,pairings[,2:1]], ncol = 2)],
  nrow(combinations), nrow(pairings),
  dimnames = list(NULL, paste(pairings[,1], pairings[,2], sep = "-"))
)
#>             1-2       1-3       2-3
#>  [1,]  8.070354 11.884214 13.555158
#>  [2,]  8.070354 18.255948 12.953167
#>  [3,]  8.070354  4.831957  2.173939
#>  [4,] 11.884214 18.255948  8.297971
#>  [5,] 11.884214  4.831957 15.626987
#>  [6,] 18.255948  4.831957 15.771459
#>  [7,] 13.555158 12.953167  8.297971
#>  [8,] 13.555158  2.173939 15.626987
#>  [9,] 12.953167  2.173939 15.771459
#> [10,]  8.297971 15.626987 15.771459
```

Comment: Thanks. This definitely speeds things up.  30 objects with a sample size of 8 takes 9.504389 secs to process with this version, and 46.89256 secs with the old (for loop) version.